# How to use server controls in Asp.net MVC with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how to use server controls in asp.net mvc.

Controls like : dropdown, grid etc...

please give me a refernece or a sample.

Is postback is supports? in mvc.

and also please provide a reference link for advance level of asp.net mvc. and MVC Projects

Answer (score 3):

answer is : you can't. refer to basic asp.net mvc article and try to understand the difference the mvc stands for before movign into advanced level.

[this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx) might be a good starting point. and [these tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/fundamentals)  are pretty good too.

and no- postbacks are not supported.

Comment: Agreed.  MVC uses the model-view-controller pattern, not server controls.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using server controls in MVC. You can just about, but it's entirely the wrong model.

When you ask are postbacks supported, the answer is yes & no. A post back is just a post to the server, so yes, you can see that request and respond. However the complex event handling present in webforms isn't supported. Controllers won't raise events, and views don't have code behinds.

It's better to use the MVC way of generating drop-downs, grids etc.